# a bash script for Unix that synchronize two directories

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu

I have this assignment for System Programing and I'm new to bash so can anybody help me please.
(I'm using Ubuntu)

***Assignment:***
Create a bash script for Unix that synchronize two directories.

**Call:** mySync [-r] / [-i] leftdir rightdir

All files that are in the left side, but not in the right list are copied from the left to the right.
All files that are in the right directory, but not in the left directory are copied from right to left.
If a file exists on both sides, the older version is replaced by the newer version.

- If the -r (recursive) function is present, recursive will synchronize all Sub-folders.
- If the -i option (interactive) is present, the existing (older) Files will be overwritten only if the user has agreed.

  *I would really appreciate the help.*

Comment: Usual question. What have you tried ?

Comment: Prease show what you have done so far or ask more specific question.

Comment: Nobody will do do your homework for you. Paste your code and ask concrete questions.

Comment: This actually sounds like _real_ homework from a class or something. Sure you don't want to solve this yourself, so that you learn to use bash?

Comment: Are you allowed to use commands such as `rsync` or `hg`?

Comment: `rsync` is a great tool to accomplish something like this, at least in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Tools you may want to use :

- `find` :  to do a listing of what each directory contains, with or without the `-maxdepth` option, and with the help of the `-printf` option that would permit you to print the listing with both the names of the files and their last modification time (both on the same line !).
- `comm` (to be used with `sort`) : to compare the two lists of files/dirs you have obtained with `find`, and to print only the files you need to transfer (see the `-1`, `-2` and `-3` options).
- and for the rest, usual Bash builtins : `read` and `getopts`

See the relevant manuals.